# Integrating JFreeChart with SpringMVC throws exception: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: spring-mvc, jfreechart

I want to display a simple graph in my webapplication so I've decided to integrate JFreeChart into Spring MVC.
I've found the following solutions:

```
@RequestMapping("/seeGraph")
    public String drawChart(HttpServletResponse response) {

        response.setContentType("image/png");
        XYDataset pds = createDataset();
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(pds);
        try {
            ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(response.getOutputStream(), chart, 600, 400);            
            response.getOutputStream().close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return "graph";
    }
```

I guess this is not good. Although it does display the graph it also throws an exception:

```
getOutputStream() has already been called for this response] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response.
```

I did some research and found that an application can either call getOutputStream or getWriter on any given response, it's not allowed to do both.

But because  of ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG() I have to call getOutputstream, and Spring will call getWriter().

Is there any clever solution to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you ask Spring to render a view called `graph` after execution of your controller method (by returning a view name from the method). However, if you write data to the output inside a controller you should not proceed to view rendering phase.

So, you need to use a `void` method instead:

```
@RequestMapping("/seeGraph")
public void drawChart(HttpServletResponse response) { ... }
```